# Change icons for file types via Registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, icons, file-types

I want to change the icons for JavaScript [`.js`] file types without the use of external software.

1. One online guide suggested to:

   1. Note the value [`Applications\Code.exe`] of the below key; *however, as far as I know, this only refers to the application this file type is opened with by default*:

      ```
      HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\.js\ProgID
      ```
   2. Change the icon path of the below key, which would change all icons for file types opened with VS Code:

      ```
      HKCR\Applications\Code.exe\DefaultIcon
      ```
2. Another [guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type) suggested to:

   1. Create subkey `HKCR\.js\DefaultIcon`, with value type `REG_SZ`, and a data value of the full path to the icon, with how many sizes this icon file contains separated by a comma *(didn't work)*: 
      [image: Screenshot]

How do I assign a custom icon for a file type that overwrites the default icon of the app that opens this file type by default?

Comment: It's defined here: `reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\JSFile\DefaultIcon` providing that `assoc .js` returns `js=JSFile`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I checked  `assoc .js` and then changed the data value in `HKCR\JSFile\DefaultIcon` to the path to my `.ico` file and rebooted my system. It is still overwritten by the icon of VSCode

Comment: Forget registry. Go to `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\resources\win32\"` (or where you have _VS Code_ installed) in file explorer and change the `javascript.ico`.

Comment: Or, maybe better, use [vscode-icons extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/09/08/icon-themes#_rebellion-mutiny-revolt-uprising) or [Create your own Icon Theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/09/08/icon-themes#_create-your-own-icon-theme).

Comment: For some reason, all files opened by VS Code only show the `default.ico` icon from the directory at `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\resources\win32\"`. I also installed the VS code Icons Extension, but it only chnages the in-app icons.